# what is the best way to create an vendor independent dal in c# without using ORM?

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, vendor-neutrality

Currently I have a project that involves two database providers:

1. SqlClient
2. OleDb

I need to create a DAL that handles these providers. I was thinking to create a interface like this:

```
public interface IDataAccessLayer
{
    public string GetSomeData();
}
```

And implement it separately (although it's simple this is the wrong way)

```
public class SqlClientDal : IDataAccessLayer
{
    public string GetSomeData() { }
}

public class OleDbDal : IDataAccessLayer
{
    public string GetSomeData() { }
}
```

I have read some post like this:

[.Net: how to create vendor independent Dataset, Tableadapters, bindings (DB decided at runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057824/net-how-to-create-vendor-independent-dataset-tableadapters-bindings-db-deci) (it's good, but it doesn't provide any example)

[Obtaining a DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z)

[Creating a Data Access Layer (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) (really good, but table adapters are vendor dependent)

I would like to create a DAL with this features:

1. Use of typed data tables (using visual studio designer)
2. Use of vendor independent data adapters (manually created)
3. Not ORM

How can I create a simple DAL with these features?

Comment: Have you looked at LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: https://github.com/robconery/massive/

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping an application database agnostic (ADO.NET vs encapsulating DB logic)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080601/keeping-an-application-database-agnostic-ado-net-vs-encapsulating-db-logic)

Answer (score 0):

Look into deriving your classes from the following classes:

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnection BaseConnection;
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter BaseAdapter;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DataAccess : DbConnection
    {
        protected override DbTransaction BeginDbTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public override void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public override string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
            }
            set
            {
                throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
            }
        }

        protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand()
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public override string DataSource
        {
            get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); }
        }

        public override string Database
        {
            get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); }
        }

        public override void Open()
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public override string ServerVersion
        {
            get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); }
        }

        public override System.Data.ConnectionState State
        {
            get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); }
        }
    }
}
```

mess around with each one of those functions and classes. It's very flexible.

Comment: Both SqlConnection, and OleDbConnection derive from DbConnection

Comment: I have reviewed that namespace, but I need an example about how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [Writing driver class generic for any database support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133804/writing-driver-class-generic-for-any-database-support). Unless you have very specific need in writing your own DbAL, I recommend using Micro ORMs like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [FluentData](http://fluentdata.codeplex.com/) or [SqlFu](https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu/wiki). The ease of use (according to me) is what's compelling with these structures.